# Can't use word 'error' in laravel route path?

Tags: laravel-5

I have a problem in laravel route study.If I defined a route like this:

```
Route::get('error/{name}',function($name){
    return "Sorry $name. Something is wrong with your account.";
});
```

Then I access it by `localhost/error/john`, browser said `not found url`.But if i change `error` to other word like 'wrong'.And I can access by `localhost/wrong/john'.So can anyone tell me what is wrong with my code?

Comment: I just test this, working fine with me, just try to create a Virtual host and then check the same scenario

Comment: I just test again. Still not work for me. I created a fresh laravel project.to test this. Just defined this single Route, My laravel version is 5.2

Comment: did you created any virtual host ?

Comment: here is my working screen shot [Shot1](http://postimg.org/image/6g0qd3y9j/) .... [Shot2](http://postimg.org/image/p8m25s9yn/) and my Route code is `Route::get('/error/{name}', function($name){
    echo 'My name is '.$name;
});`

Comment: I tested the above scenario on Laravel 5.1 and 5.2 .... do one try by this... in your route, just add backslash before error eg: `::get('/error/{name}' ....)....`

Comment: I can access by this `http://localhost:10086/index.php/error/john`,but other routes don't need `index.php`,

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just put laravel in htdocs folder. And it worked fine. So there must be something wrong in virtualhost. I willl try to find out. Thanks again.